# Rust and tokio::postgresql, use of moved value

Tags: multithreading, rust, async-await, rust-tokio, tokio-postgres

I am working on this kind of code:

`database.rs`

```
use tokio::task::JoinHandle;
use tokio_postgres::{Client, Connection, Error, NoTls, Socket, tls::NoTlsStream};

use crate::secret;

pub struct DatabaseConnection {
    pub client: Client,
    pub connection: Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>
    // pub connection: JoinHandle<Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>>
}

impl DatabaseConnection {

    async fn new() -> Result<DatabaseConnection, Error> {

        let (new_client, new_connection) = DatabaseConnection::create_connection().await.expect("Error, amazing is amazing");

        Ok(Self {
            client: new_client,
            // connection: tokio::spawn( async move { new_connection } )
            connection: new_connection 
        })
    }

    async fn create_connection() -> Result<(Client, Connection<Socket, NoTlsStream>), Error> {
            // Connect to the database.
        let (client, connection) =
            tokio_postgres::connect(
            &format!(
                "postgres://{user}:{pswd}@localhost/{db}",
                    user = secret::USERNAME, 
                    pswd = secret::PASSWORD, 
                    db = secret::DATABASE
                )[..], 
            NoTls)
            .await?;

        Ok((client, connection))
    }
}


pub async fn init_db() -> Result<(), Error> {

    let database_connection = 
        DatabaseConnection::new()
            .await;

    let db_connection = tokio::spawn(async move {
        if let Err(e) = database_connection {
            println!("Connection error: {:?}", e);
        }
    });

    let create = database_connection.unwrap().client
        .query("CREATE TABLE person  (
            id        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
            name      VARCHAR NOT NULLL;
        )", &[]).await?;
    
    Ok(())
    
}
```

`main.rs`

```
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    
    match database::init_db().await {
        Ok(()) => println!("Successfully connected to the database"),
        Err(e) => eprintln!("On main: {}", e)
    }     
}
```

I can't use the `database_connection` variable to perform my `SQL` statements because it's moved into the `tokio routine`.

I already tried to return on my struct a `connection: tokio::spawn( async move { new_connection } ), but the routine it's never spawned, till i call the attribute, and returns an ended database connection.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advice

Comment: why do you spawn a task for the connection ?

Comment: The connection object performs the communication with the database, so need to avoid block the main thread execution.
https://docs.rs/tokio-postgres/0.5.3/tokio_postgres/#example

Comment: Have you notice the example split the tuple ? async is HARD I advice to learn Rust without it because trying to code anything in async.

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going with 2 concurrent tasks (a concurrent event loop for the connection) allows sharing your connection between various program modules, and have a non-blocking (potentially non-async) query API.

It is possible to achieve by implementing a [reactor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern), but not as trivial as in some other languages, because Rust is going to make sure you follow the strict multi-thread correctness.

Let's say that task 1 is your main program, it spawns task 2 - a DatabaseConnection reactor event loop. Since this instance might be accessed by multiple threads potentially at the same time to start or process an SQL query, wrap it with `Arc<Mutex<DatabaseConnection>>`.

To execute a query task 1 needs to send an SQL command to task 2, and wait for the result. One way to do this is to use an [mpsc](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/mpsc/index.html) channel for sending commands, and [oneshot](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.9.0/tokio/sync/oneshot/index.html) for the result. `oneshot` is similar to a promise/future in principle: you can await on one end, and push the value and wake from the other end.

For some code example check out the [channels tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/channels). The "Spawn manager task" chapter is gonna be a part of your DatabaseConnection task 2 waiting for SQL queries and processing them. The "Receive responses" chapter that shows how to use `oneshot` to send the result back.

Also note that `async` doesn't imply that you have to block on `await`. If your program is simple enough, there's a possiblity to avoid having the reactor while still not blocking. This can be done with `tokio::select!` inside a loop. An example of such usage can be found in [the select tutorial](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/select) - chapter "Resuming an async operation". Imagine that `action()` is your `.query()` method. Note that they are calling it, but not `await`-ing. Then the `select!` is able to return when the query operation results are ready, and if they are not ready - you are free to do any other async work.